# How to determine whether an indirect effect is statistically significant using Bayesian statistics?

Tags: bayesian, bayes, mediation

I've used bayesian estimation to test the indirect effects within a model and identified 95% credible intervals. 
I'm typically used to using the Sobel's z test to identify significant mediation, what is the Bayesian alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You would look at the 95% credible interval for the *ab* effect (the product of the two slopes involved in the indirect effect). At each iteration of the MCMC, you can compute the product of the estimates of the two slopes, then obtain the 95% credible interval for this posterior distribution of the product of the two slopes.